Inversion of an exponential integral
For $f,g:\mathbb{R}\to [0,\infty)$, is it possible to invert the following
$$
f(x)=\int_0^\infty \exp\left(-\int_{x-t}^{x+t} (t-|y-x|)g(y)\,dy\right)\,dt
$$
If not, what properties can I infer on $g$ from $f$?
Some thoughts:
If
$$
h(x)=\exp\left(-\int_{x-t}^{x+t} (t-|y-x|)g(y)\,dy\right)
$$
I can use the d'Alembert operator $\square=\partial_{tt}-\partial_{xx}$ to get
$$
g(x)=-\frac12 \square \log h(x)
$$
However, I have $f(x)=\int_0^\infty h(x)\,dt$, what can I say from here? Should I apply the Leibniz rule for improper integrals under some properties of $g$?
